# Convert String to numeric vector

Tags: r, string, vector, type-conversion

I have a function which takes a vector of zeros and ones for example:

```
foo(c(1,1,1,0,1,1))
```

But in some cases, there are more then 100 numbers and I have to add all commas manually. Is there any predefined function to convert a string to such a vector? Something like this:

```
foo(unknown_function("111011"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `paste`

```
foo <- function(vec){
   paste(vec, collapse="")
  }

foo(c(1,1,1,0,1,1))
#[1] "111011"
```

If we need to do the reverse

```
foo1 <- function(str1){
      as.integer(unlist(strsplit(str1, "")))
  }
res <- foo1("111011")
res
#[1] 1 1 1 0 1 1
```

Or may be the OP meant

```
dput(res)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I mean the other direction. foo should still take the vector c(1,1,1,0,1,1). But I'm looking for another function which converts the string "111011" to a vector c(1,1,1,0,1,1).

Comment: Awesome. That's what I'm looking for. Thanks a lot.